# Formula for the distance to the kernel of a functional.

Tags: functional-analysis

It's true that in a normed space $X$ we have $d(x,\ker(f))=\frac{|f(x)|}{\|f\|}$ for any $x\in X$ and $f \in X^*$?

Comment: Hi and welcome! Can you please add some context (e.g. definitions) to your question?

Comment: My guess is that this works if and only if your space is reflexive, where we can represent $f$ with some kind of inner product.

Comment: I agree, it seems that in this case, writing $f(x) = \langle x,y\rangle$), $d(x,\textrm{ker}(f)) = |\textrm{proj}_y x| = \left| \dfrac{\langle x, y\rangle}{|y|^2}y \right| = \dfrac{|\langle x,y \rangle |}{|y|}$.

I couldn't quickly come up with a counterexample for other spaces, but a guess out of nowhere is that $f = \delta$ and $X = C^\infty$ might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you must assume $f \ne 0$ for your equation to be defined.

For any $y \in \text{ker}(f)$ we have $\|x - y\| \ge |f(x)|/\|f\|$.
In the other direction, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $z \in X$ with
$f(z) = 1$ and $\|z\| \le (1+\epsilon)/\|f\|$.  Then $y = x - f(x) z \in \ker(f)$
with $\|x - y\| = |f(x)| \|z\| \le (1 + \epsilon) |f(x)|/\|f\|$.  Take $\epsilon \to 0+$.

Comment: Can you please tell how did you deduced that $y\in ker(f) $ , we have $||x-y||\geq |f(x)| / ||f||$ ?

Comment: By definition of the norm on $X^*$, $|f(x-y)| \le \|f\| \|x-y\|$, but $f(x-y) = f(x)-f(y) = f(x)$.