# a convex closed set of a Banach space contains no closest point

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

I need to prove that:

For the Banach space $E=C([0,1])$ with $||.||_{\infty}$ and the closed convex set $A=\{f \in E : f(1)=0 \}$, can we find an element $f \in E$ such that $A$ contains no closest point to $f$.

Comment: Do you mean to say that there exists $g\in E$ such that the distance $d(g,A)$ is not attained? (That is, there is no $h \in A$ such that $d(g,A)=||g-h||$)

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF. Yes, can we prove this?

Comment: There is something wrong in your question. The always vanishing map satisfies the equality of your second paragraph. Also your first paragraph doesn’t make sense. If a subset is not empty, then a point in it is at a zero distance from it.

Comment: No point that is closest to what?

Comment: I have updated the question. Sorry about that.

Comment: Surely $0$ is a closest point.

Comment: @math_for_ever Your update doesn't answer my question.  The phrase "contains no closest point" suggests that you're trying to measure a "closest point" **to some other set**.  What is that other set?

Comment: to $f$, I have updated the question again.

Comment: If you take $f=0$ then it has a closest point. Please stop and think about what you are asking and formulate it correctly.

Comment: He probably wants to show that for $f \in E \setminus A$ there is no $g \in A$ such that $ d(f,A)=||f-g||$ (i.e., $A$ is not a proximinal set)

Comment: @EvangelopoulosF. Thanks, but I don't want to guess and the OP needs to be a bit more precise.

Comment: You guys are right, I should write the question in a precise way. I have updated one more time. I hope it is precise now. My apologies!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is not true.

Consider the functional $\delta_1 \colon E \to \mathbb R $ defined via $\delta_1(f)=f(1)$ (the dirac functional). Then $ ||δ_1||=1$. Notice that $A=\ker \delta_1$. Thus for all  $ f \in E$
$$d(f,A) = d(f, \ker \delta_1) =\frac{|\delta_1(f)|}{||\delta_1|| } = |f(1)|$$
([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1162140/formula-for-the-distance-to-the-kernel-of-a-functional)). Let $ f \in E$ be given. If we pick $g \in E$ such that $g(x)=f(x)-f(1)$ we have that $g \in A $. Then
$$||f-g||= \sup | f(x)-f(x)+f(1)| =|f(1)| = d(f,A)$$
and so the distance is always attained.

Edit: If $X$ is a nonreflexive Banach space (like $C([0,1]))$, then by James's theorem, there exists $x^* \in X^*$ that is not norm attaining (that is, there is no $x \in B_x$ such that $ ||x^*||=|x^*(x)|$. It is not hard to see that the subspace $ V=\ker x^*$ doesn't have the best approximation property. To see this, note that for all $x \in X$
$$d(x,V)= \frac{|x^*(x)|}{||x^*||} .$$
Arguing by contradiction, suppose that there exists $x \in X$ such that $ d(x,V)=||x-v||$ for some $v \in V$. Then, $ |x^*(x-v)| = |x^*(x)|= ||x^*|| \ || x-v||$. In other words,
$$ ||x^*|| = |x^* \left ( \frac{ x-v}{||x-v||}\right )|$$
which is impossible since $x^*$ is not norm
attaining (note that $\frac{ x-v}{||x-v||} \in B_X$)

Comment: So, Is there a Banach space $E$ and a closed convex set $A$ of $E$ and an element $x \in E$ such that $A$ contains no closest point to $x$??

Comment: check my edit, and also check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481843/a-counter-example-of-best-approximation)